# Find the length of an inner array in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have an array

```
var arr:Array = new Array( {num1:1, num2:2}, {num1:1, num2:2} );
```

And i want to get the length of  the first inner array like this:

```
trace(arr[0].length); //should return 2 but it doesnt work
```

Also why **arr[0][0]** doesnt work?
i have to specify **arr[0]['name']**

Comment: {} is used to represent objects, [] are used for array declaration. Change it to [] in the array constructor.

Comment: [num1:1, num2:2] this returns an error, i want to set names for the array

Comment: `[1, 2]`. Arrays are not associative in AS3

Comment: You are right, {} is used for associative array, for ( in ) can be used to loop through the object properties, you might want to write a function whch loops through these properties and returns the count.

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_16.html

Comment: @Alex you want to use the name as values or index ?

Comment: @Alex, I edited my answer, let me know if you need something else,

Answer (score 5):

you are declaring an array of objects ...,

Array of array is like

```
var arr:Array = new Array( [1,2],[1,2] );
```

and then you can have your arr[0].length.

---

To add the names as index, you can use your first declaration, and modify it a bit,

```
 var arr:Array = new Array( {num1:[1,2], num2:[2]}, {num1:[1,2,3], num2:[1,2]} );
```

so now we have an array arr that contains objects which contains arrays,
to read the elements you can :

```
for each(var o:object in arr){
   o.num1.length(); // give you the legth of the array inside num1 = 2 for the first case,
   o.num2.length(); 
}
```

the question is, will all the objects inside your array be the same or not ? because if they don't, it's going to be a little hard for you to read the elements ... let me know, and I hope this helps ... 
Cheers !!

---

Found something else that might help you, [array access](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#array_access), and you can access using something like this : `obj["num"+1]` which make it more dynamic and easier to handle